# How To make Scrollable our Freedom View controller using constraints?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, storyboard, autolayout

[image]

Actual image is.....
[image]

```
->View controller

   ->view

     ->ScrollView[[top,bottom,leading,trailing]to its super view]

       ->contentView[[top,bottom,leading,trailing,vertical,horizontal]to its scrollview].
```

that actual image is for iphone6 ->iphone4s,Any one help me how to do this.....

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to set constraint with scrollview then little bit extraa effort is required for handling scrolling so that Scrollview + autolayout works.
    First of All What exactly take place when autolayout is used : 
When you use the auto layout, your views will resized automatically based on the constraint properties.

But, when you use a UIScrollView with auto layout like a container, the auto layout not works like expected. 
so Here is Very good tutorial [g8production](http://www.g8production.com/post/57513133020/auto-layout-with-uiscrollview-how-to-use) which clears this confusion. Big Thanks goes to g8Production for providing this tutorial.

Comment: mark it correct answer if it solved your problem . Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I think you are setting the constraints for content view in wrong way. You are trying to set the constraints on contentView that are related to its container(scrollview) which don't know content size of its own. It determines its content size from what it contains (in your case contentView,). Both are dependent to each other for their size. So both are confused.
To solve this you should first set the fixed height and width of contentView and then make outlets of these constraints and update these constraints with the height and width of superview when your view loads.

Answer (score 0):

add top, bottom , leading and trailing space to your scroll view to view. It should be set accordingly, how you you want it to be seen. Then set same for content view (image). just addheight and width constraint for your image.

Misha :)